# python3 converting binary data to string and back

Tags: python, python-3.x, jpeg

I'm opening an image in binary mode with python3
then splitting that data at a specific marker (\xff\xda)

everything that is after that marker is stored in a variable
for which I'd like to replace all a's by e's

but I'm having troubles when converting the binary data to string :

> UnicodeDecodeError : 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position
>   13: ordinal not in range(128)

```
with open(filein, "rb") as rd:
  with open(fileout,'wb') as wr:
    img = rd.read()
    if img.find(b'\xff\xda'): ## ff da start of scan
        splitimg = img.split(b'\xff\xda', 1)
        wr.write(splitimg[0])
        scanimg = splitimg[1]

        scanglitch = ""
        scanimg = scanimg.encode()

        for letter in scanimg :
            if letter not in 'a': 
                scanglitch += letter
            else :
                scanglitch += 'e'

    print(scanimg)

    wr.write(b'\xff\xda')
    content = scanglitch.decode()
    wr.write(content)
```

Isn't encode() and decode() the right way 
to convert binary data to strings and back ?
thx

Comment: Please show us the traceback too, so we can tell which line gives you that error.

Comment: Are you sure you need to convert to string in the first place? `b"this is a byte string".replace(b"a", b"e")` can replace "a" with "e" without ever using strings.

Comment: sorry, traceback error comes from the line with "scanimg = scanimg.encode()" not sure how to add this to my post since the line numbers don't match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with binary data, you'll want to try and remain in binary mode as much as possible, especially since there's no guarantee your chosen string encoding can represent all values anyway.

Just remember `bytes` objects are fundamentally lists of 8-bit unsigned integers, even if they have the convenient string-like `b'xyz'` syntax.

```py
filein = "download.jpeg"
fileout = "glitch.jpg"

with open(filein, "rb") as rd:
    img = rd.read()
    # We can happily crash here if there's no FFDA; 
    # that means we're not able to process the file anyway
    prelude, marker, scanimg = img.partition(b"\xff\xda")
    scanglitch = []

    for letter in scanimg:  # scanimg is a list of integers, so we have to use `ord()`
        if letter != ord("a"):
            scanglitch.append(letter)
        else:
            scanglitch.append(ord("e"))

with open(fileout, "wb") as wr:
    wr.write(prelude)
    wr.write(marker)
    wr.write(bytes(scanglitch))
```

(I am aware the replacement logic could be written as a list comprehension, but I figured it'd be more friendly like this.)